# Append all values stored in 'maxi' to a list using python?

Tags: python, list, append

I want to append all values stored in variable `maxi` to an empty list. I have tried `c.append(maxi)` and `c.extend(maxi)` but it is not working.

```
import numpy as np
import re
import gdal
import ogr
from osgeo import gdal_array
from gdalconst import *
import os
import osr
import shutil
import h5py
import subprocess
import operator
#np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
indir = '/home/vigna/Documents/LST_29_03'
directory=os.fsencode(indir)
e=1
for file in os.listdir(directory):    
    file1=os.fsdecode(file)    
    if '_Gadchiroli' in file1:
        b=str(e)+'_Gadchiroli.tif'
        #print(file1)
        gadchiroli=gdal.Open(b,GA_ReadOnly)
        #print(gadchiroli)
        gad_arry=gadchiroli.ReadAsArray()
        #print(gad_arry)
        c=[]
        maxi=np.amax(gad_arry)
        #print(maxi)
        c.append(maxi)       
        e+=1
print(c)
```

Output of print(maxi):

[image]

I want to store all these values in single list.

Comment: you keep setting `c` to an empty list on each iteration... `c=[]`

Comment: As just suggested, move c=[] outside the forloop

Comment: I tried this code with creating empty list(c=[]) outside of the loop. still not working. @juanpa.arrivillage

Comment: print(c) gives [0.0] as an output. I am not getting all values of "maxi" in a "c". @F.Leone

Comment: Identified a mistake. Thank you for answering here.